# How to insert a character after every n characters in a huge text file using C#?

Tags: c#, file, insert

It would be preferable if the code is able to create a new file.
eg: If my file originally is:
fsyfugiuhknklmoiuiuutyughvhjbiuhi
jhiubuguygfvtdrcrsresetgfcyuhijoj

and the new file desired contains a new line char after every 3rd position:
fsy
fug
iuh
knk
...

what should be the code.?

Comment: Visit each character and if(currentIndex % n == 0) { //code to insert character } which is O(N).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void InsertACharacterNoStringAfterEveryNCharactersInAHugeTextFileUsingCSharp(
    string inputPath, string outputPath, int blockSize, string separator)
{
    using (var input = File.OpenText(inputPath))
    using (var output = File.CreateText(outputPath))
    {
        var buffer = new char[blockSize];
        int readCount;
        while ((readCount = input.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            if (readCount == buffer.Length)
                output.Write(separator);
        }
    }
}

// usage:
InsertACharacterNoStringAfterEveryNCharactersInAHugeTextFileUsingCSharp(
    inputPath, outputPath, 3, Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: This seems really efficient. The code is pretty short and the function is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you (I have provided the underlying logic of inserting characters after every n characters...)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "fsyfugiuhknklmoiuiuutyughvhjbiuhi jhiubuguygfvtdrcrsresetgfcyuhijoj".ToCharArray();
            var elementsToConsider = 3;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(input.Skip(i).Take(elementsToConsider).Aggregate("",(a, b) => a + b));
                i = i + (elementsToConsider  -1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...

```
public string Tweak( string s , char c , int n )
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( s.Length + ( s.Length % n ) + 1 ) ;
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < s.Length ; ++i )
  {
    sb.Append( s[i] ) ;
    if ( i % n == 0 ) sb.Append( c ) ;
  }
  return sb.ToString() ;
}
```

That's probably as good as you'll get. Though you might get slightly better performance using arrays of char (`char[]`) and array block copy operations using the class `System.Buffer`'s method `BlockCopy` and instantiating the new string via `new String( outputBuffer )`. The length of the resulting string is the length of the source string, L, plus L % n, where n is periodic length. Add 1 to the length of the output buffer if the last [and possibly short] segment at the end should have the trailing character added.